# Quiver algebras with finite global dimension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a fixed connected quiver $Q$.
Are there only finitely many quiver algebra $KQ/I$ (I an admissible ideal) up to isomorphism which have finite representation type and finite global dimension?

Comment: If you take $Q$ to be a loop and $K=\mathbb{Q}$ then $KQ=\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Among its quotients you find all finite field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. There are infinitely many of those and all of them have finite representation type and global dimension $0$.

Comment: @FernandoMuro For me in the definition of quiver algebra, I is an admissible ideal.

Comment: Mare, for me the quiver algebra is actually the path algebra. Now that you added a condition on the ideal $I$ my previous answer doesn't work.